# SQL check if group is continuous when ordered and return broken groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to find a way to list rows, that are breaking continuous groups of records. I say groups, because we could use `GROUP BY` to list values of groups (but that is not applied, we need particular rows).

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (ID INT, NNO INT, DIDX INT, SIDX INT);

-- Valid sample rows
INSERT INTO Test (ID, NNO, DIDX, SIDX) VALUES
    ( 1,    107     , 7898, 0  ),
    ( 2,    102     , 7883, 0  ),
    ( 3,    53      , 7877, 0  ),
    ( 4,    62      , 7877, 42 ),
    ( 5,    101     , 7870, 81 ),
    ( 6,    103     , 7918, 42 ),
    ( 7,    110     , 7920, 42 ),
    ( 8,    100     , 7919, 0  ),
    ( 9,    24      , 7921, 0  ),
    (10,    85      , 7904, 0  ),
    (11,    85      , 7905, 0  ),
    (12,    85      , 7906, 0  ),
    (13,    85      , 7907, 0  ),
    (14,    85      , 7908, 0  ),
    (15,    85      , 7911, 0  ),
    (16,    112     , 7876, 0  ),
    (17,    5       , 7891, 42 ),
    (18,    80      , 7912, 42 ),
    (19,    66      , 7912, 91 ),
    (20,    22      , 7912, 81 ),
    (21,    60      , 7911, 42 ),
    (22,    60      , 7912, 0  ),
    (23,    78      , 7891, 81 );

-- Disecting row
INSERT INTO Test (ID, NNO, DIDX, SIDX) VALUES 
    (24,    666     , 7906, 120);
```

**EDIT:** I probaly mislead some answers a bit by providing an example too much simplified. It then appeared that perhaps the groups could be only broken by a single row. So please add another row into the example data set:

```
-- Disecting row -2-
INSERT INTO Test (ID, NNO, DIDX, SIDX) VALUES 
    (25,    444     , 7906, 160);
```

Now if ordered the rows in this particular order:

```
SELECT ID, NNO, DIDX, SIDX
FROM Test 
ORDER BY DIDX, SIDX;
```

...the last inserted row will break (disect) group of records, which have `NNO=85`:

```
ID          NNO         DIDX        SIDX
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
...
10          85          7904        0
11          85          7905        0
12          85          7906        0
24          666         7906        120       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
25          444         7906        160       <<<<<<<<<<<< after EDIT <<<<<<<
13          85          7907        0
14          85          7908        0
15          85          7911        0
...
```

The result should say `85`, which is the broken group, or `NULL` if we would use healthy data without row `ID=24`.

Another way to look at the problem is, that for each group (even if it contains 1 row), there may not be records of another group which start or end lies between start and end of the queried group. In the provided example, queried group (85) starts with `DIDX=7904` and `SIDX=0` and ends with `DIDX=7911` and `SIDX=0` and nothing can fall into the range - which is the case of record `ID=24`.

I so far tried some approaches like using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...)`, using `WITH` with `MIN` and `MAX` to go through each group and check, if there are rows that fall within (failed so far to construct it) and `GROUP BY` with `MIN` and `MAX` with aim to cross check it with table rows. No attempt is really worth publishing, so far.

Could anyone advice, how I could check continuity of such defined groups?

Comment: Could you explain more why this row ID=24 "brakes" the group ? Because of SIDX=120, or NNO=666 ?

Comment: Where's you query???

Comment: Could a valid group be bookended by rows with different NNO yet consecutive DIDX?

Comment: @krokodilko It breaks the group ID=85 in the given order (as per shown query)

Comment: @Eric I don't get what query; all parts are given, including the query to list the rows in specific order.

Comment: @shawnt00 The order is given by the provided query, which contains `ORDER BY DIDX, SIDX`. The consequent NNO could be different, but if NNO repeats (the value is present more than once), they must be following each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so inspired by given answers (which I voted up for helping), I came with this code that seems to provide the desired result. I'm not sure though, if it's the cleanest and shortest possible way.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT NNO, 
           DMIN, 
           DMAX,
           SMIN,
           SMAX,
           LEAD(DMIN) OVER (ORDER BY DMIN, SMIN) as nextDMIN,
           LAG(DMAX) OVER (ORDER BY DMIN, SMIN) as prevDMAX,
           LAG(SMAX) OVER (ORDER BY DMIN, SMIN) as prevSMAX,
           LEAD(SMIN) OVER (ORDER BY DMIN, SMIN) as nextSMIN,
           CNT
    FROM (
        SELECT NNO, 
               MIN(DIDX) as DMIN, 
               MAX(DIDX) as DMAX, 
               MIN(SIDX) as SMIN, 
               MAX(SIDX) as SMAX,
               COUNT(NNO) as CNT
        FROM Test
        GROUP BY NNO
        ) as SRC
    )

SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE ((prevDMAX > DMIN OR (prevDMAX = DMIN AND prevSMAX > SMIN)) OR 
       (nextDMIN < DMAX OR (nextDMIN = DMAX AND nextSMIN < SMAX)))
      AND CNT > 1
```

Perhaps I should give a little explanation. The code finds `MIN` and `MAX` border values for each parameter `SMIN` and `DMIN` and then find those values for previous and next rows. We also `COUNT` number of rows in a group.

The conditions in brackets basicaly say, that no record of other group can be in `DMIN` and `DMAX` range, and if it's on the borders of the range, then it has to be outside `SMIN` or `SMAX`. Finally, a broken group must have more then 1 row; otherwise the query would return not only offendee group, but also first offender.

I should say, that this code has a little flaw and that is a case when there would be an offender with more than one row intact in between ofendee group rows. I should be able to tackle this in post processing, where I have to shuffle rows to achieve intact groups.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
  ID
  ,NNO
  ,DIDX
  ,SIDX
  ,LAG(NNO) OVER (ORDER BY DIDX, SIDX) as previousNNO
  ,LEAD(NNO) OVER (ORDER BY DIDX, SIDX) as nextNNO 
FROM Test
) 
SELECT 
 previousNNO as BrokenGroup
FROM CTE
WHERE previousNNO=nextNNO 
AND NNO<>previousNNO
```

I used a CTE and WINDOW functions to also keep track of the previous and next group (NNO) for each row. A broken group will be one that has a different current group while the previous and next are the same. From your example with ID 24.

```
ID          NNO                     DIDX        SIDX
----------- -----------             ----------- -----------
...
12          85  < previous group    7906        0
24          666 < current group     7906        120       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
13          85  < next group        7907        0
...
```

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel. I am voting up this answer, because it works with the given example and it's clean. However, this approach will not work in case the group is broken by more then one consequent row. I admit I didn't stated specifically that more than one row can break the group, but I meant to find *any* broken group.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that any consecutive range of `DIDX` should only have one `NNO`. As such there will be no two valid groups that abut each other.

This should help identify the offenders:

```
with data as (
    select NNO, DIDX, dense_rank() over (order by DIDX) as rn
    from Test
)
select min(DIDX) as range_start, max(DIDX) as range_end
from data
group by DIDX - rn
having count(distinct NNO) > 1;
```

Getting the actual rows:

```
with data as (
    select ID, NNO, DIDX, dense_rank() over (order by DIDX) as rn
    from Test
), groups as (
    select DIDX - rn as grp, min(DIDX) as range_start, max(DIDX) as range_end
    from data        
    group by DIDX - rn
    having count(distinct NNO) > 1
), data2 as (
    select *, lead(NNO) over (partition by grp order by DIDX) as next_NNO 
    from Test t inner join groups g
        on t.DIDX between g.range_start and g.range_end
)
select * from data2 where NNO <> next_NNO;
```

If you're looking for a test to run prior to inserting a row:

```
with data as (
    select NNO, DIDX, row_number() over (order by DIDX) as rn
    from Test
)
select case when min(DIDX) is not null then 'Fail' else 'Pass' end as InsertTest
from data
group by DIDX - rn
having @proposed_DIDX between min(DIDX) and max(DIDX)
    and @proposed_NNO <> min(NNO);
```

Comment: I think this answer is pretty close (I'm still going through it). The fist sentence is a bit simplified, the result *does* depend on `SIDX`, even though it is important only for the first and last row of a group; for any row between evaluating `DIDX` consequent values is sufficient and what you stated is true. So I'm amending your answer in this regard and will test it.